# How to waterproof leaking 3-layer shell fabric

Tags: waterproofing, waterproof-clothing

I have a few older (5+ years) but not excessively used "waterproof" breathable clothing items (pants, jackets), that are not waterproof in high-abrasion areas such as knees, shoulders, crotch.

Is there a good way of waterproofing these areas?

Since these areas will quickly wet out regardless of DWR status, I'm ok with losing breathability in these areas.

I was thinking of maybe applying diluted silicone locally - either as spray or caulking+mineral spirits. Would that work?

Other solutions are welcome too of course.

Comment: If you haven't already, have a look through the other questions on this site with the `waterproofing` and `waterproof-clothing` tags. None of them quite answer your question, but you might get some ideas to try as well as learn a few things to avoid.

Comment: There are transparent stick-on patches that you can get for patching a hole in a down jacket. I don't know if they'd be durable and flexible enough for your purposes.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few manufacturers of soaps and products specially designed for cleaning and treating waterproof and waterproof-breathable gear, to extend their usefulness. Two that come to mind are Nikwax and Granger's. First you wash the item, to remove dirt and other soaps (that are said to be incompatible with the waterproof gear), then you spray on or wash in the re-waterproofing product.